model.name="unknown" termination condition: infeasible message from solver: Ipopt 3.11.1\x3a Converged to a locally infeasible point
The infeasible error arose when I changed the definition of m.Tm() from
pyo.Var(m.k0)

to:
pyo.Param(m.k0, mutable=True, default=0).
I don't want Pyomo to alter m.Tm(), I want Pyomo to calculate it's values.
Here is my code:
def rc_estimator_train(T_in, T_in_m1, T_in_m2, T_out, T_out_m1, T_out_m2, GHI, Q, Q_m1, Ro, Co, Rm, Cm, sample_rate, flag_train):

    m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

    m.Tin = T_in
    m.To_m1 = T_out_m1

    N = np.size(m.To)-1 
    m.k0 = pyo.RangeSet(0, N)
    m.k1 = pyo.RangeSet(1, N) 
    
    m.Ro = pyo.Var(within=pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, 10), initialize=0)
    m.Co = pyo.Var(within=pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, 100000), initialize=0)   
    m.Rm = pyo.Var(within=pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, 10), initialize=0)        
    m.Cm = pyo.Var(within=pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, 100000), initialize=0)   
        
    m.x = pyo.Var(m.k0)
    m.Tm = pyo.Param(m.k0, mutable=True, default=0)

    bounds = 10

    m.y = pyo.Var(m.k0, bounds=(-bounds, bounds))
    m.ypos = pyo.Var(m.k0, bounds=(0, bounds))
    m.yneg = pyo.Var(m.k0, bounds=(0, bounds))
    m.ysum = pyo.Constraint(m.k0, rule = lambda m, k: m.y[k] == m.ypos[k] - m.yneg[k])       
    
    m.ic_1 = pyo.Constraint(rule = lambda m:
                            m.Tm[0] == m.Tin[0]
    )       
    m.ic_2 = pyo.Constraint(rule = lambda m:
                            m.x[0] == m.Tin[0]
    )           

    m.Tm_update = pyo.Constraint(m.k1, rule = lambda m, k:                                                                                                                                        
                                    m.Tm[k] == m.x[k-1] + (m.Tm[k-1] - m.x[k-1])*pyo.exp(-1*sample_rate*(m.Rm*m.Cm))
                                    if (k < N+1) else pyo.Constraint.Skip
    ) 

    m.x_update = pyo.Constraint(m.k1, rule = lambda m, k:                                                                                                                                        
                                    m.x[k] == (m.Rm*m.Rm/(m.Rm + m.Ro))*m.To_m1[k] + (m.Ro/(m.Rm+m.Ro))*m.Tm[k-1] 
                                    + (m.x[k-1] - (m.Rm*m.Rm/(m.Rm + m.Ro))*m.To_m1[k] - (m.Ro/(m.Rm+m.Ro))*m.Tm[k-1])*pyo.exp(-1*sample_rate*(m.Rm + m.Ro)/(m.Rm*m.Ro*m.Co))
                                    if (k < N+1) else pyo.Constraint.Skip
    )      

    m.y_output = pyo.Constraint(m.k0, rule = lambda m, k: m.y[k] == m.x[k] - m.Tin[k])
    
    m.yobj = sum(m.ypos[k] + m.yneg[k] for k in m.k0)
    m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = m.yobj, sense=pyo.minimize)
    
    return m

These are the outputs from the model:
Variables:
    Ro : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value              : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :     0 : 1.8967615211145494 :    10 : False : False : NonNegativeReals
    Co : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value               : Upper  : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :     0 : 0.06338591566179329 : 100000 : False : False : NonNegativeReals
    Rm : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value              : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :     0 : 1.4913161536269557 :    10 : False : False : NonNegativeReals
    Cm : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value                 : Upper  : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :     0 : 8.172494390281837e-15 : 100000 : False : False : NonNegativeReals
    x : Size=16, Index=k0
        Key : Lower : Value              : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          0 :  None : 24.399999999998663 :  None : False : False :  Reals
          1 :  None : 15.090893888788246 :  None : False : False :  Reals
          2 :  None : 15.090893888788257 :  None : False : False :  Reals
          3 :  None : 15.287821300620102 :  None : False : False :  Reals
          4 :  None : 14.864705017820587 :  None : False : False :  Reals
          5 :  None : 15.199399204913151 :  None : False : False :  Reals
          6 :  None : 15.318600234326782 :  None : False : False :  Reals
          7 :  None :  16.05351247002624 :  None : False : False :  Reals
          8 :  None : 16.045196119136918 :  None : False : False :  Reals
          9 :  None :  16.82336376655795 :  None : False : False :  Reals
         10 :  None :  16.81992493792016 :  None : False : False :  Reals
         11 :  None : 16.742807591142913 :  None : False : False :  Reals
         12 :  None : 16.613114625375218 :  None : False : False :  Reals
         13 :  None :  16.76354767042075 :  None : False : False :  Reals
         14 :  None :  16.74635352723185 :  None : False : False :  Reals
         15 :  None :  17.16763938489963 :  None : False : False :  Reals
    y : Size=16, Index=k0
        Key : Lower : Value                   : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          0 :   -10 : -1.3362497679640582e-12 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          1 :   -10 :      -9.309106111210735 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          2 :   -10 :      -9.409106111210715 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          3 :   -10 :       -9.21217869937889 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          4 :   -10 :       -9.63529498217836 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          5 :   -10 :      -9.300600795085831 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          6 :   -10 :      -8.881399765672244 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          7 :   -10 :      -7.946487529972888 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          8 :   -10 :      -7.954803880862212 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          9 :   -10 :      -7.176636233441265 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         10 :   -10 :      -7.080075062079065 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         11 :   -10 :      -7.157192408856302 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         12 :   -10 :      -7.386885374623976 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         13 :   -10 :       -7.23645232957846 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         14 :   -10 :      -7.253646472767358 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         15 :   -10 :      -6.832360615099624 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
    ypos : Size=16, Index=k0
        Key : Lower : Value                  : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          0 :     0 :    0.06324006278404506 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          1 :     0 : 0.00032480821316208813 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          2 :     0 : 0.00032132658581701407 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          3 :     0 : 0.00032825343291005544 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          4 :     0 :  0.0003136437459894271 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          5 :     0 : 0.00032508151456777897 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          6 :     0 : 0.00034051581465620307 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          7 :     0 :  0.0003807128529392047 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          8 :     0 :  0.0003803130737358376 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          9 :     0 : 0.00042167105131939137 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         10 :     0 :  0.0004274313078950001 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         11 :     0 : 0.00042281209740707855 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         12 :     0 : 0.00040962403118248415 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         13 :     0 :  0.0004181588236870904 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         14 :     0 : 0.00041716337387299535 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         15 :     0 : 0.00044295509377180193 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
    yneg : Size=16, Index=k0
        Key : Lower : Value              : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          0 :     0 : 0.0632400627853813 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          1 :     0 :  9.309430919423388 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          2 :     0 :  9.409427437796017 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          3 :     0 :  9.212506952811298 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          4 :     0 :  9.635608625923823 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          5 :     0 :   9.30092587659989 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          6 :     0 :  8.881740281486415 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          7 :     0 :  7.946868242825394 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          8 :     0 :  7.955184193935513 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
          9 :     0 :  7.177057904492192 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         10 :     0 : 7.0805024933865734 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         11 :     0 :  7.157615220953318 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         12 :     0 :  7.387294998654755 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         13 :     0 : 7.2368704884017525 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         14 :     0 :  7.254063636140835 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
         15 :     0 :  6.832803570193023 :    10 : False : False :  Reals

  Objectives:
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Value
        None :   True : 121.91005543960651

  Constraints:
    ysum : Size=16
        Key : Lower : Body                    : Upper
          0 :   0.0 :  -1.309110083542912e-17 :   0.0
          1 :   0.0 :  -5.080380560684716e-13 :   0.0
          2 :   0.0 :  -5.151434834260726e-13 :   0.0
          3 :   0.0 :  -5.027089855502709e-13 :   0.0
          4 :   0.0 :  -5.275779813018744e-13 :   0.0
          5 :   0.0 :  -5.080380560684716e-13 :   0.0
          6 :   0.0 :  -4.849454171562684e-13 :   0.0
          7 :   0.0 :  -4.334310688136611e-13 :   0.0
          8 :   0.0 : -4.3431924723336124e-13 :   0.0
          9 :   0.0 : -3.9257486150745535e-13 :   0.0
         10 :   0.0 :  -3.872457909892546e-13 :   0.0
         11 :   0.0 : -3.9168668308775523e-13 :   0.0
         12 :   0.0 : -4.0323300254385686e-13 :   0.0
         13 :   0.0 : -3.9523939676655573e-13 :   0.0
         14 :   0.0 :   -3.97015753605956e-13 :   0.0
         15 :   0.0 :  -3.730349362740526e-13 :   0.0
    ic_1 : Size=1
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper
        None :     0 : 24.4 :     0
    ic_2 : Size=1
        Key  : Lower : Body               : Upper
        None :  24.4 : 24.399999999998663 :  24.4
    Tm_update : Size=15
        Key : Lower : Body                   : Upper
          1 :     0 :  4.462208380573429e-12 :     0
          2 :     0 :  2.758682171588589e-12 :     0
          3 :     0 :  2.758682171588589e-12 :     0
          4 :     0 :  2.794209308376594e-12 :     0
          5 :     0 : 2.6556534749033744e-12 :     0
          6 :     0 :  2.708944180085382e-12 :     0
          7 :     0 : 2.7480240305521875e-12 :     0
          8 :     0 : 2.8848035071860068e-12 :     0
          9 :     0 : 2.8812507935072063e-12 :     0
         10 :     0 : 3.0233593406592263e-12 :     0
         11 :     0 : 3.0198066269804258e-12 :     0
         12 :     0 : 3.0055957722652238e-12 :     0
         13 :     0 : 2.9629632081196178e-12 :     0
         14 :     0 : 2.9842794901924208e-12 :     0
         15 :     0 : 2.9771740628348198e-12 :     0
    x_update : Size=15
        Key : Lower : Body                    : Upper
          1 :   0.0 : -2.1871014208585393e-06 :   0.0
          2 :   0.0 : -2.1871014102003983e-06 :   0.0
          3 :   0.0 : -2.2156287808883235e-06 :   0.0
          4 :   0.0 :   -2.21562870983405e-06 :   0.0
          5 :   0.0 : -2.2726836288455843e-06 :   0.0
          6 :   0.0 : -2.2726836821362895e-06 :   0.0
          7 :   0.0 : -2.3772843711356018e-06 :   0.0
          8 :   0.0 :  -2.377284367582888e-06 :   0.0
          9 :   0.0 : -2.4913942198168115e-06 :   0.0
         10 :   0.0 :  -2.491394226922239e-06 :   0.0
         11 :   0.0 :  -2.481885040594989e-06 :   0.0
         12 :   0.0 : -2.4818850086205657e-06 :   0.0
         13 :   0.0 : -2.5104123757557772e-06 :   0.0
         14 :   0.0 : -2.5104123722030636e-06 :   0.0
         15 :   0.0 : -2.5769764739891343e-06 :   0.0
    y_output : Size=16
        Key : Lower : Body                   : Upper
          0 :   0.0 : -4.294247350698628e-16 :   0.0
          1 :   0.0 : 1.0178524689763435e-12 :   0.0
          2 :   0.0 :  1.028510610012745e-12 :   0.0
          3 :   0.0 :  1.007194327939942e-12 :   0.0
          4 :   0.0 : 1.0533796057643485e-12 :   0.0
          5 :   0.0 : 1.0178524689763435e-12 :   0.0
          6 :   0.0 :  9.734435479913373e-13 :   0.0
          7 :   0.0 :  8.704148513061227e-13 :   0.0
          8 :   0.0 :  8.704148513061227e-13 :   0.0
          9 :   0.0 :  7.851497230149107e-13 :   0.0
         10 :   0.0 :  7.736034035588091e-13 :   0.0
         11 :   0.0 :  7.833733661755105e-13 :   0.0
         12 :   0.0 :  8.064660050877137e-13 :   0.0
         13 :   0.0 :  7.904787935331115e-13 :   0.0
         14 :   0.0 :  7.913669719528116e-13 :   0.0
         15 :   0.0 :  7.460698725481052e-13 :   0.0


Ipopt will only calculate values for variables. Parameters are not touched. "I don't want Pyomo to alter m.Tm(), I want Pyomo to calculate it's values." I am not sure there is a difference between altering and calculating its values.
